# DEF ratings for mounted characters

Tags: iron-kingdoms

In Iron Kingdoms: Full Metal Fantasy, how is the Defense of a mounted character calculated? P105 of Full Metal Fantasy specifies that "A character’s base Defense is the sum of his Speed (SPD), Agility (AGL), and Perception (PER)" and p215 states, "While mounted, a character uses the SPD of his mount instead of his own." It's not clear whether this applies solely to movement, or to all calculations involving the SPD stat. With that in mind, is the Defense of a mounted character based on their own Speed stat, or that of their mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **permanent** changes to SPD affects a character's DEF score (See core rules page 106). For instance, your DEF isnt changed due to your armor's SPD penalty, otherwise you would be penalized twice.

So, to calculate the rider's DEF:

> DEF = normal DEF - 4 + Ride Skill